# Blocking version of System.IO.Stream.Read(byte[], int, int)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using `System.IO.Stream.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)`. Is there an alternative to that method (or a property to set) so that the method won't return until all count is read (or end of stream is reached)? Or should I do something of like this:

```
int n = 0, readCount = 0;
while ((n = myStream.Read(buffer, readCount, countToRead - readCount)) > 0)
    readCount += n;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[BinaryReader.ReadBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes.aspx) blocks in the desired way. That's not equivalent to reading to the end of the stream, however. (You don't want to call `BinarReader.ReadBytes(int.MaxValue)` - it will try to create a 2GB buffer!)

I tend to use a MemoryStream for reading all the data from a stream of an unknown size. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream) for sample code.