# Why does MemoryStream.GetBuffer() always throw?

Tags: windows, exception, memorystream, getbuffer

The following code will always throw 
UnuthorizedAccessException  (MemoryStream's internal buffer cannot be accessed.)

```
byte[] buf1 = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
var ms = new MemoryStream(buf1);
byte[] buf2 = ms.GetBuffer();      // exception will be thrown here
```

This is in a plain old console app and I'm running as an admin. I can't imagine a more privileged setting I could give this code. So why can't I get at this buffer? (And if nobody can, what's the point of the GetBuffer method?)

The MSDN docs say

> To create a MemoryStream instance with
>   a publicly visible buffer, use
>   MemoryStream,
>   MemoryStream(array[], Int32,
>   Int32, Boolean, Boolean), or
>   MemoryStream(Int32).

Am I not doing that?

P.S.  I don't want to use ToArray() because that makes a copy.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor#system-io-memorystream-ctor(system-byte())) is the documentation for `MemoryStream(byte[])` constructor that you're using. It specifically says:

> This constructor does not expose the underlying stream. GetBuffer throws UnauthorizedAccessException.

You should use [`MemoryStream(Byte[], Int32, Int32, Boolean, Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor#system-io-memorystream-ctor(system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32-system-boolean-system-boolean)) constructor instead, with `publiclyVisible = true`.

Comment: If you don't want to specify all the parameters of the constructor, just to get to the publiclyVisible parameter, you can use the one with only the int32 parameter, as specified in the @Dolphin's answer.

Answer (score 8):

Check the docs for [MemoryStream.GetBuffer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx)

> To create a MemoryStream instance with
>   a publicly visible buffer, use
>   MemoryStream, MemoryStream(Byte[],
>   Int32, Int32, Boolean, Boolean), or
>   MemoryStream(Int32). If the current
>   stream is resizable, two calls to this
>   method do not return the same array if
>   the underlying byte array is resized
>   between calls. For additional
>   information, see Capacity.

You need to use a different constructor.

Answer (score 6):

To add to what others have already put in here...

Another way to get your code to work is change your code to the following line.

```
byte[] buf2 = ms.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be using `MemoryStream(array[])` which does not match any of the three versions mentioned in the docs.