# Reset or Clear .NET MemoryStream

Tags: .net, memorystream

The .NET MemoryStream does not appear to have a .Reset or .Clear method.

I was thinking of using the following code to accomplish this:

```
ms.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
ms.SetLength(0)
```

What is the proper way to clear or reset an existing .NET MemoryStream?

Comment: **Just to clear this question.** I think he's wondering which method prevents memory being allocated. In theory, `SetLength(0)` should retain `Capacity` while assigning a `new MemoryStream()` should free this memory and allocate new. Depending on use, one might wish to preserve memory and just reset the stream's `Length` and `Position`. *(anyway, this is how a memory conscious C++ programmer would think)*

Comment: **And the OP's code is legit.** `.Capacity` remains after those instructions so it's the best way to avoid a free/alloc when not necessary.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The memorystream does not have a reset/clear method because it would be redundant. By setting it to zero length you clear it.

Of course you could always do:

```
memoryStream = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.Capacity());
```

This would yield you a memorystream of the same size that is initialized.

If you really want to manually clear the stream I suspect you would have to resort to looping through the elements.

Comment: -1 Why a new Stream of same capacity when you could `.SetLength(0);` and retain capacity? Memory abuse in action.

Comment: also doesnt work if you use the stream with a using statement. Would prefer .SetLenght(0) too

Comment: That is why my answer points out that setting it to zero length clears it.. then elaborates on how to get a stream of the same length that is initialized by the constructor.

Answer (score 106):

Why do you need resetting memory stream? You always can create a new one. Or you can use:

```
memoryStream.SetLength(0);
```

Comment: Came across this late but Andrew is correct. Leaving this here since I had to check. MSDN: If the specified value is larger than the current capacity and the stream is resizable, the capacity is increased ... stream between the old and the new length are initialized to zeros.

Comment: Thats not working when you reread data into the stream. Position and length will be 0!

Comment: Creating a new memorystream causes an allocation. Some programs are performance-sensitive and every allocation counts.

Comment: @NicFoster What's the purpose of `memoryStream.SetLength(0)`? Will I be able to write to the stream again?

Comment: @silkfire, it clears the memory stream, so you can reuse it, as opposed to creating a new one which will allocate memory (slower).

Comment: Since capacity is retained what if you write to it a larger capacity stream. Will it increase the capacity automatically to the new length or error out?

Answer (score 34):

Since a MemoryStream is essentially a byte array with an index (and some other supporting members) clearing the byte array and resetting the index can be considered resetting and clearing the MemoryStream. If the initial state of a MemoryStream is a zeroed array with a position of zero then an example of a MemoryStream reset may be:

```
public static void Clear(this MemoryStream source)
{
  byte[] buffer = source.GetBuffer();
  Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  source.Position = 0;
  source.SetLength(0);
}
```

It is incorrect to say that MemoryStream.SetLength alone resets or clears the MemoryStream since SetLength only clears the internal buffer array if the length exceeds the current buffer's length.

Reinitializing a MemoryStream is a valid approach but less efficient. One benefit of reinitializing the MemoryStream would be to guarantee that the stream was never closed. Once the MemoryStream is closed it can no longer be changed. If you can ensure that the MemoryStream instance isn't closed then clearing the buffer may be the way to go.

Comment: .Reset() shouldn't be zeroing the data right?  Only .Clear() should do that...  PS - Any way to read the data length after the stream is closed?  (ie: without private reflection hopefully)

Comment: Just want to underscore an important point here: if you use the buffer directly, you *are* at risk of reading 'old' data if you don't zero the buffer when you reset the position to zero. However, if you stick to using the Read() methods, this *won't* happen - bytes past the 'end' of the stream are not copied from one buffer to the other.

Comment: Always getting an exception for a valid non-empty stream when calling `source.GetBuffer()`: _MemoryStream's internal buffer cannot be accessed_. **upd**: here explained why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1646219/44217

Comment: setting the length to 0 also sets the position to 0, so setting the position is redundant

Comment: This is the best answer from a security perspective. For example: when using a MemoryStream with a CryptoStream, you can ensure that the memory is zeroed immediately when you are done with it instead of waiting for the garbage collector to get around to deallocating the objects (if that even zeros the bytes).

Answer (score 1):

I used **DotMemory** to Profile @Rana_Ian solution, and I called GC to enforce full collection.
I found that large **Streams** will stuck in **LOH**!
And after adding one extra line

```
public static void Clear(MemoryStream ms)
{
    var buffer = ms.GetBuffer();
    Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    ms.Position = 0;
    ms.SetLength(0);
    ms.Capacity = 0; // <<< this one ******
}
```

I clicked on **F12** to see `Capacity` Implementation, And I found this (I simplified generated code a little bit - I'm using Resharper):

```
public virtual int Capacity
{
  get
  { .... // some code }
  set
  {
    if ((long) value < this.Length) { // throw some ex }
    if (!this._isOpen) { // some another code }
    if (!this._expandable && value != this.Capacity) { //MemoryStreamNotExpandable }
    if (!this._expandable || value == this._capacity) return;
    if (value > 0)
    {
      byte[] numArray = new byte[value];
      if (this._length > 0)
        Buffer.InternalBlockCopy((Array) this._buffer, 0, (Array) numArray, 0, this._length);
      this._buffer = numArray;
    }
    else
      this._buffer = (byte[]) null; /// <<<< that's it! I need this one
    this._capacity = value;
  }
}
```

So It's clearing the Buffer, I'm not sure if this is correct or not!

Answer (score -1):

you can create your memorystream like this:

```
public class ResettableMemoryStream : MemoryStream
{
    public void Reset()
{
    Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
}
```

and after your operation in your code call:

```
 buffer.Reset();
```

Comment: Looking at the decompiled code of Seek function, it only resets Position, but not Length.