# Do I need to reset a stream(C#) back to the start?

Tags: c#, .net

I don't know too much about streams in C#. Right now I have a stream that I put into a stream reader and read it. Later on in some other method I need to read the stream(same stream object) but this time I get this error

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Stream was not readable."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize)
       at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream)
       at ExtractTitle(Stream file) in :line 33
       at GrabWebPage(String webPath) in :line 62
       at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__7()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

So I am thinking maybe by reading the stream it goes to the end. Then when I try to read it again it is at the end of the stream and thats why I am getting this error.

So can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 117, accepted):

When you read a stream to the end, specifically with [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)'s [`ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) method, you have to [`Seek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek.aspx) it back to the beginning. This can be done like so:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
sr.ReadToEnd();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //StreamReader doesn't have the Seek method, stream does.
sr.ReadToEnd(); // This now works
```

Comment: This looks like a better method than just closing it, and looks like the correct answer. +1

Comment: Does StreamReader have seek? I can't find it.

Comment: No; stream does. Change `sr.Seek` to `stream.Seek` in the code above.

Comment: Slightly simpler syntax: `stream.Position = 0;`

Comment: @chobo2 You can call the underlying stream of `StreamReader` by calling `StreamReader.BaseStream`.

Answer (score 45):

Your conclusion is correct; once you've reached the end of your stream, you won't be able to read more data until you've reset your position within the stream:

```
myStream.Position = 0;
```

This is equivalent to seeking back to the beginning.  Note that your stream must support seeking for this to work; not all streams do.  You can check this with the `CanSeek` property.

Comment: Well how can I get a stream that does? Like I am trying to "GetResponseStream()" back from an ftp request and this returns a "Stream" this does not support "Seeking" so what should I do?

Comment: Can you read the entire stream in one go?  If so, read it into a byte array, then create a new MemoryStream (which supports seeking) from that array.

Comment: How can I read it into a byte array? Like won't I need to figure out the size of the stream first to know how to big to make the byte array?

Comment: Read it in small chunks (say, 1024 bytes), and write that chunk to the MemoryStream.  Jon Skeet's wrote a good answer about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream

Comment: A more elegant approach IMO.

Comment: It doesn't always work, for example with `System.IO.Packaging.ZipWrappingStream` I get `NotSupportedException`

Answer (score 5):

Use `BaseStream` for `StreamReader`:

```
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pFileStream);
 sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```