# Error at creating Zip file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zip

I'm using Ionic.Zip library to zip all files into a folder, so I do:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
     foreach(var i in consultaPDF)
     {
         var fileRoute = carpeta + i.vRutaArchivo;
         zip.AddFile(fileRoute, "Document");
     }

     zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
}
```

That I want to do is just download zip file. I don't want to save it. How can I just download it? Regards

I change it to:

```
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                    foreach(var i in consultaPDF)
                    {
                        var fileRoute = carpeta + i.vRutaArchivo;
                        zip.AddFile(fileRoute);
                    }
                    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
                    zip.Save(output);
                    return File(output, "application/zip", "sample.zip");

            }
```

Zip is downloaded correctly but when I try to open it:

> the file has an unknown format or is damaged

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to reset a stream(C#) back to the start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746092/do-i-need-to-reset-a-streamc-back-to-the-start)

Comment: 0 bytes @mjwills

Comment: I don't know why is a dupplicate of stream I don't use it @mjwills

Comment: `I don't know why is a dupplicate of stream I don't use it` What do you think a `MemoryStream` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset stream position to start after saving zip to it

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    foreach(var i in consultaPDF)
    {
        var fileRoute = carpeta + i.vRutaArchivo;
        zip.AddFile(fileRoute);
    }
    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    zip.Save(output);
    output.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return File(output, "application/zip", "sample.zip");
}
```

Comment: Excelent answer. Thankyou!

Comment: It is exactly the same as the answer in the duplicate @David.