# C# - Microsoft Graph API with iTextSharp - Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft API Graph API to get a PDF file from my OneDrive which I have successfully got via this line:

```
var streamFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["{item-id}"].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

Now I want to take a the stream of this file and edit it with iTextSharp

```
using (MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream())
{

    //Dont know what to replace this with

    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("Uploads/Document.pdf");

    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outFile);

    AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

    fields.SetField("Full_Names", "aaa");

    pdfStamper.Close();

    pdfReader.Close();

}
```

And then upload it back to OneDrive, which I am able to do via this:

```
//Don't know what to replace this with

var uploadPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/NewDocument.pdf");

byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadPath);

Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);

await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["{item-id}"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
```

So my question is how do I take my file that I got and use iTextSharp to do its thing? So I can upload this new edited file?

**UPDATE**

I tried this:

```
var streamFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["{item-id}"].Content.Request().GetAsync();

            using (MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(streamFile);
                PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outFile);
                AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

                fields.SetField("Full_Names", "JIMMMMMMAYYYYY");

                await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["{item-id}"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument-2.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(outFile);

                pdfStamper.Close();
                pdfReader.Close();
            }
```

But got this error:

> Cannot access a closed Stream.

I can see the file is being uploaded to my OneDrive, but when I goto open it I get this error:

> Failed to load PDF document.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

When I remove these last two lines:

```
pdfStamper.Close();
pdfReader.Close();
```

I don't get Cannot access a closed Stream error anymore, my file uploads but I get an error when I open it:

> Failed to load PDF document.

**UPDATE**

When I try this

```
var streamFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["{item-id}"].Content.Request().GetAsync();

await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["{item-id}"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument-2.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(streamFile);
```

It uploads the file I grabbed, so that part is working, but I can't edit it with iTextSharp.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you along:

[Do I need to reset a stream(C#) back to the start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746092/do-i-need-to-reset-a-streamc-back-to-the-start)

Once you read a stream, you need to reset it back to the beginning to do something else with it.

Comment: try setting "outFile.Position = 0" right before your graph putAsync call.

Comment: Also, not sure where I remember seeing this, but I think the max size is 4MB. Might want to verify that as well. Otherwise, you'll want to use upload session.

Comment: Yea I read that too, my files even after editing is no where near that.

Comment: I'll try your solution in the morning, I dont have access to the code right now