# Opening a file from a pack URI in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I am looking to open a .csv file from the application pack to do some unit testing. So what I would really love is some analog to `File.ReadAllText(string path)` which is instead `X.ReadAllText(Uri uri)`. I haven't as yet been able to find this.

Does anyone know if it is possible to read text / bytes (don't mind which) from a file in the pack without compiling this file to disk first?

Oh and btw, `File.ReadAllText(@"pack://application:,,,/SpreadSheetEngine/Tests/Example.csv")` didn't work for me.. and I am already doing the `var app = new Application()` trick to make sure I have a pack started up during my unit test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just get the stream from the Application.GetResourcePart() return value and use a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) to read all the text out using the ReadToEnd member.

Answer (score 12):

I was just looking to do the same thing and ended up using Application.GetResourceStream. Below is a code example. I used the ReadFully method from [Creating a byte array from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/221941/744014).

```
string imagePath = "pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;Component/Assets/Images/image.png";
StreamResourceInfo imageInfo = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(imagePath));
byte[] imageBytes = ReadFully(imageInfo.Stream);
```