# finding file in root of wpf application

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, visual-studio, relative-path

I'm trying to load a file with pack://application: The file is situated in the root of my project but I keep getting a null reference error. However When I do an absolute reference it finds the file and loads just fine.
What am I missing here?

This doesn't work

```
var txt = Application.GetContentStream(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Layout.xml"));
string full = new StreamReader(txt.Stream).ReadToEnd();
```

or any variation with Pack://Application,,,/

This works, but I don't want to use it and seems bad practice anyway

```
var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Substring(0, (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Length - 10));
var txt = path + @"Layout.xml";
string full = new StreamReader(txt).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532381/opening-a-file-from-a-pack-uri-in-wpf

Comment: And welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ensure that the file is definitely copied into your output `./bin/` directory on compile:

[image]

This worked perfectly for me in my WPF application:

```
const string imagePath = @"pack://application:,,,/Test.txt";
StreamResourceInfo imageInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(imagePath));
byte[] imageBytes = ReadFully(imageInfo.Stream);
```

If you want to read it as binary (e.g. read an image file), you'll need this helper function. You probably won't need this, as you're reading an `.xml` file.

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

For more, see [Microsoft on Pack URIs in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Programming_with_Pack_URIs).

Comment: If the file you want to access is in any sub-folder in the Visual Studio solution folder, it will get copied into that sub-folder on compile. You will need to adjust the path in the `pack://` string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the way you are trying to achieve this. I use to solve this kind of problem differently:

First, embed the file you are trying to access in you application. This is done by setting the Build-Step-Property of the File (Properties-Window, when file is selected in VS) to **Embedded Resource**.

In your application, you can recieve a stream to that resource like that:

```
var stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.yourfile.txt");
```

If you are unsure of the string you have to pass to `GetManifestResourceStream(..)`, you can inspect what embedded resources are available and look for the one that is accociated with your file like so:

```
var embeddedResources = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
```