# Bind database image to the ad rotator control

Tags: asp.net, adrotator

I am using asp.net 2.0 and C#.

I have a adrotator control, whcih I am binding to the database which has the three fields.
AlternateText, ImageUrl and NavigateUrl.

Now, this works fine, as per the expectation. My question is this that the ImageUrl in the table contains a URL like http://www.xyz.com/abc.jpg 
but I want to store image in a database and then bind the image to the adrotator.

please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a requirement to store the image as binary data in the database?  It's almost never the best way to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to put the data of the image into a [`image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(SQL.90).aspx) field in the database. This can be achieved by reading the image from the web with a [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx). You can then get the [`HttpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) with :

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Then  read the bytes from the [response stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) (See this SO question [Creating a byte array from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream)) . Then insert this `byte[]` into your database.

Then, you could use a [custom handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c67a8bd(VS.80).aspx) to read the image from the database and output it as `image/jpeg` (or whatever mimetype you need).