# Equivalent of $_FILES in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's the equivalent of PHP's $_FILES variable in C#? Or at least something that accesses the files in the same way. I've got an upload form that I can't change and need to find out how to get at these files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at `Request.Files`, for example:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile item in Request.Files)
{
    var filename = item.FileName;

    var fileBytes = new byte[item.ContentLength];
    item.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, item.ContentLength);

    // fileBytes now contains the content of the file
    // filename contains the name of the file
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because the use of `Stream.Read()` is buggy: it might not read the entire content length. You would have to use a loop; or you could instantiate a `MemoryStream` and then use `item.InputStream.CopyTo()`.

Comment: @Rob: because it might take some people slightly more than 21 seconds to write a meaningful, non-stupid comment.

Comment: @Timwi, it's not buggy in the slightest, by the time you can access Request.Files, all the content is available for processing. I have code in production use that proves such..

Comment: @Rob: Sorry, it is buggy. Read up on the contract for `Stream.Read()`.

Comment: @Timwi, Stream.Read is an *abstract* method, ergo there's no implementation there to be buggy...

Comment: @Rob: If you read up on Stream.Read carefully you'll see that you CANNOT reliably read it in one go. It may return you just 1 byte even if there are more available. The fact that a specific use case works is a fluke and an implementation detail, which the implementor may choose to change.

Comment: @Rob: I said *contract*, not *implementation*. Since it is abstract, it is *particularly important* to know its contract before calling it. If you don’t know this, you shouldn’t be writing code that uses abstract methods, because you’ll be generating bugs.

Comment: I take it you're alluding to "An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has not been reached."? Whilst it might be "an implementation detail, which the implemtor may choose to change", I deem it reasonable to rely on the implementation of the .net framework that I'm targeting and its current behaviour. Yes, service packs have changed behaviours previously, but that's why testing occurs prior to the deployment of framework updates to production systems.

Comment: @Rob... there’s nothing wrong with making a mistake, even the best developers do. But a good developer can live up to a mistake and learn from it. You’re trying to reason it away and maintain your ego. Consequently, you will generate the same bug again in the future.

Comment: Timwi, I'm sure you will apologize to Rob for your mistake. Unless you want to say that the documentation of HttpPostedFile.InputStream at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx is wrong to use the same example that Rob is using. Besides, if you bother to use Reflector to check HttpInputStream you will see that it contains the entire file contents in memory and returns all available bytes.In the end, both Save and Read will call the same GetBytes method, with the same arguments. Seems you need don't know streams as well as you thought

Comment: What you are suggesting is to *look at an internal implementation detail using Reflector* and then to go ahead and *write code that assumes this internal implementation*. This is called tight coupling and is a common source of hard-to-find bugs. Code contracts were invented to mitigate this. (And yes, I’m afraid the MSDN example has the same bug.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream for a correct way to read all bytes from a stream. Observe also a an answer with -6 votes that does it your way.

Answer (score 2):

You will have an `HttpRequest` object passed in to your handler, right? Just access that object’s `Files` property:

```
for (int i = 0; i < request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    var file = request.Files[i];
    // Do something with this file, for example:
    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(someDirectory, file.FileName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sometimes ( for example with uploadify ) the HttpPostedFileBase parameter:

Ex:

```
public ActionResult UploadPicture(HttpPostedFileBase fileData){
  img = Image.FromStream(fileData.InputStream, true, true);
}
```