# SharePoint 2010 Silverlight web part - download multiple files from web to document library

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

There is a need to download multiple files from a web location to the SharePoint 2010 document library using a Silverlight 4.0 web part.

Is it possible to achieve this without downloading files to the local computer and then uploading them back to the SP server? How would this be done?

Can Silverligth open a stream as it's running in the sandbox? Having an out of the browser application with elevated privileges is not an option.

If not, must isolated storage be used as we have multiple files to be downloaded and re-uploaded to the document library? Is there another option? Files are a few MBs large, so the isolated storage size would have to be increased.

Thanks

Comment: does it have to be a silverlight webpart? because you are quite limited with the silverlight object model - with a "normal" visual webpart you could use the server object model...also what do you mean with "quite large"?

Comment: Yes, it would have to be a Silverlight webpart as there are other features besides this one. File size would be a few MBs and the SL isolated storage(not OOB) is limited to 1MB.

Comment: okidok, ive added an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can upload files to SharePoint without temporary saving it to disc. Somebody had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723478/sharepoint-2010-upload-file-using-silverlight-4-0), the only difference is that he reads the byte array from disk. To download/stream the content from a different web address, i'd suggest you use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class (which also supports async downloading). I don't think you need to adjust the isolated storage.

Just found another [another article](http://deepumi.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/multiple-file-uploading-in-silverlight/) on google, you might want to change that code to your like.

Note that SharePoint has a (default) max. upload size of 50mb (iis7 has 30mb) - you can change this in the web.config, but it needs to be applied to all servers).