# Have ASP.NET C# web form access multiple files on computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, file, include

I have a file, call it `main.dat`. Inside it has lines like `include file-a.dat`, `include file-b.dat` and I have logic that handles these inputs. I would like to be able to upload `main.dat` via asp.net (C#) web forms project, and have IT access `file-a.dat` which should be in the same folder. If I use something like silverlight-multifile-uploader, then it takes all of them (in alphabetical order) and reads them in one by one, in which I cannot control the order, which I want to be in the same order as the includes are in `main.dat`.

1. Is there a way to solve this problem directly, i.e., just upload `main.dat` and have my code access the specified files? (I know this is a long shot since this could cause SO many security issues) and if not,
2. Is there a way I can use the [silverlight-multifile-uploader](http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/) (maybe via javascript) so that I can specify the order given the input files? Like if `file-b.dat` needs something in `file-d.dat` and `file-d.dat` was in fact included, then make that one the first one read?
3. Any alternate (better) solutions than the two I've thought of?

Answer (score 1):

How big are the files? Can you afford uploading them all, even the ones which wont be referenced in the end?

If they are small, you can save them to `Dictionairy<string,MemoryStream>` and sort & process them in memory.

Comment: Relatively small: One random set gave 49.7 kB. Would I be able to just upload `main.dat` and have my program access the other needed files and add them to the dictionary? In any case, can you give an example of how this would work? or a link to an example? Thanks! (My ultimate goal is to just click on `main.dat` and have the program pull the other files.)

Comment: I believe that the browser will not allow you to access a file which hasn't been selected by the user, you won't be even able to see the path of the file.

Comment: The user will have to select all of the files.

Comment: But if I select `main.dat` it tells me the path in the `include file-a.dat`. It is assumed that they are all in same folder next to each other. Does that change anything? -- Edit: So by selecting all the files, we give the browser implicit permission to access those files, would I be able to select one, then have my code 'get' the other files and ask the user for explicit permission to access those?

Comment: As this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8282248/1160340 indicates, after selecting the files in Silverlight you get an collection of FileInfo objects, which already have the permission to read.