# Access Local Files from IIS "silverligh"

Tags: iis, silverlight, iis-7, silverlight-4.0

In a silver-light application I'm using to the following code in my Visual Studio development environment 
it works fine

```
  FileStream file = new FileStream(@"D:\OP20TS.jpg", FileMode.Open);
     but when publish website on iis it give me
```

```
File Operation to not permitted Access to path D:\OP20TS.jpg is denied
```

I have tried to give IIS full permission to the path but not work how to handle this point
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please learn Silverlight basics again. It runs within your browser, so can only access `D:\` on the browser machine, not on IIS machine (when you run in VS the two machines happen to be the same one).

Comment: the VS machine and the IIS machine are the same i develop on the same machine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276923/how-to-access-the-local-file-system-in-silverlight