# WCF live video streaming

Tags: c#, wcf, video, stream, live

I'm trying to stream a live video from a capture device via WCF.

I use `directX.capture` dll.

I've tried to capture it frame by frame and send each frame in NetTcpBinding.
when the binding transfer mode was on 'Buffered', it threw an exception that the data is to large for the xml quotat to read. and when the transfer mode was 'Stream'  I received the stream, but when i called Image.Save(fileName,Stream) (or anything else that try to access the stream) i get an exception of "parameter is not valid".
I've tried to send Bitmap or Stream, same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot save a stream directly. But you can convert a stream to a byte array, and then save the byte array.

See : [Creating a byte array from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream)
for how to convert a stream to a byte array.

Comment: allready tried that, when i convert the stream to a byte's array i get the invalid argument exception