# C# - Creating byte array of unknown size?

Tags: c#, class, arrays, byte

I'm trying to create a class to manage the opening of a certain file. I would one of the properties to be a byte array of the file, but I don't know how big the file is going to be. I tried declaring the byte array as :

```
public byte[] file;
```

...but it won't allow me to set it the ways I've tried. br is my BinaryReader:

```
file = br.ReadBytes(br.BaseStream.Length);

br.Read(file,0,br.BaseStream.Length);
```

Neither way works. I assume it's because I have not initialized my byte array, but I don't want to give it a size if I don't know the size. Any ideas?

edit: Alright, I think it's because the Binary Reader's BaseStream length is a long, but its readers take int32 counts. If I cast the 64s into 32s, is it possible I will lose bytes in larger files?

Comment: To answer your second question, the files would have to be larger than two gigabytes before this becomes a problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - while true since this is the limit imposed by the runtime, it could become a problem with significantly smaller files due to memory pressures on the machine.

Comment: @Walkerneo - Note that the signature of this method allows you to make a smaller array, say of 4096 bytes, and then call it in a loop while the result of the `Read` method is the same as the number of bytes you've requested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had no problems reading a file stream:

```
 byte[] file;
 var br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("c:\\Intel\\index.html", FileMode.Open));
 file = br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length);
```

Your code doesn't compile because the Length property of BaseStream is of type `long` but you are trying to use it as an `int`. Implicit casting which might lead to data loss is not allowed so you have to cast it to `int` explicitly.

**Update**

Just bear in mind that the code above aims to highlight your original problem and should not be used as it is. Ideally, you would use a buffer to read the stream in chunks. Have a look at [this question and the solution suggested by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream)

Answer (score 1):

You can't create unknown sized array.

```
byte []file=new byte[br.BaseStream.Length];
```

PS: You should have to repeatedly read chunks of bytes for larger files.

Answer (score 1):

BinaryReader.ReadBytes returns a byte[]. There is no need to initialize a byte array because that method already does so internally and returns the complete array to you.

If you're looking to read all the bytes from a file, there's a handy method in the File class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx