# convert byte[] to image

Tags: c#, type-conversion, byte

I have uploaded an Image in to my database as `byte[]` and now im trying to display it out.

There was an error - Argument Exception was unhandled by user code `Parameter is not valid`

At this line

```
newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Here is my codes

```
for (int i = 0; i < topRatingList.Count; i++)
            {
                int commentRating = topRatingList[i].CommentRating;
                int drinkID = topRatingList[i].DrinkID;

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    DrinkMenuDAO drink = DrinkMenuBLL.getDrinkMenu(drinkID);
                    LinkButton1.Text = drink.DrinkName; 
                    ImageButton1.ImageUrl = byteArrayToImage(drink.DrinkImage);
                }
            }


private string byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image newImage;
        string strFileName = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/images/") + ".jpg";
        if (byteArrayIn != null)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
            {
                newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                newImage.Save(strFileName);
            }
            return strFileName;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

---

the code that i used to store the image

```
protected void bn_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_msg.Text = "";
        Stream imgStream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader imgBinary = new BinaryReader(imgStream);
        bytes = imgBinary.ReadBytes((Int32)imgStream.Length);
        imgBinary.Close();
        imgStream.Close();
        string src = byteArrayToImage(bytes);
        if (src.Equals(""))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Temp/UploadedImage.jpg";
        }
    }

    private string byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image newImage;
        string strFileName = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + "UploadedImage.jpg";
        if (byteArrayIn != null)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
            {
                newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                newImage.Save(strFileName);
            }
            return strFileName;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DrinkMenuBLL.uploadImg(bytes);
        lbl_msg.Text = "uploaded";
    }
```

I used `varbinary(MAX)` in the database and the sql that i used

```
public static void UploadImg(byte[] drinkImage)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constring.getConString());

        string sql = "Update DrinkMenu set drinkImage = (@imgData) where drinkID = 4";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@imgData", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = drinkImage;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your `byte[]` represents the image correctly?  Can we see the code that stores it?

Comment: bytes = imgBinary.ReadBytes((Int32)imgStream.Length);
This is not a good way to read a file. Jon Skeet has a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream (he used to have an excellent blog post discussing various methods, but I can't find it).

Answer (score 1):

One problem could be the following one:

```
bytes = imgBinary.ReadBytes((Int32)imgStream.Length);
```

What if the stream Length is more than Int32.MaxValue as it's a Int64? Maybe you are truncating your image... use this method instead to read the stream to a buffer:

```
public static Byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
{
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[(16 * 1024)];

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Int32 read;

        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, read);

        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}

protected void bn_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_msg.Text = "";

    Byte[] bytes = ReadStream(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
    String src = byteArrayToImage(bytes);

    if (!src.Equals(""))
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Temp/UploadedImage.jpg";
}
```

Comment: sry but i dun quite get it.. how should i use it?

Comment: does the upload code have problem? it's not with the display part with the memory stream? that is mention above it?

Comment: See my comment to the original question.

Comment: Next time I'll use something different in you prefer D:
Anyway, this is how a Stream should be correctly read :S

Comment: For the upload portion I have a `img1` and it does show the picture that I am going to upload. The problem is with after storing in database where i am taking from the database the bytes and convert it back to image

Comment: I agree. I just thought it was funny that I posted the link and at almost the same moment, you posted the code from the link... But the link also explains why his method will fail (because Stream.Read won't necessarily return as much as you ask for, and particularly, network streams that will return a packet at a time).

Comment: This is what i get after changing the codes. `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The parameterized query '(@imgData binary(8000))Update DrinkMenu set drinkImage = (@imgDa' expects the parameter '@imgData', which was not supplied.`

Comment: Have you tried debugging byte data to see if everything is correct now for what concerns Stream reading? Have you checked the content of Byte[] in SQL upload function? Seems something is going wrong in between...

Comment: SqlCommand command = ....
command.Text="INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE_NAME (image) values (@image)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgData", drinkImage);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Im updating the database which currently do not have the image value in the first place