# String to byte[] and byte[] to Image in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, fingerprint

I am using [NITGEN's Fingkey Hamster DX](http://www.nitgen.com/eng/product/finkey.html) for capturing a finger print.

I have converted the fingerprint data to a text format which gives me a string like the following (string "sr" in below code gives this string):

> AQAAABQAAAAEAQAAAQASAAEAZAAAAAAA*AAAAOHbWlAewfLK7kOnScKzeN5HMVcDmjce0KPkeqyeiWEdTnJutHvnhyrnkW9OPbQNQc7/94lnozdd3Zz8RKiRSj8HHdCMZ8XIdaCy0tCxp2wLwRbVrHl14QkJlQMGqeJyzu06h/ZorwN5vVoxuzFDM9dKyqlm85XHuOeoeACxO/xZrE3NdH4aesbYWgy2i5Cru2AHymemLVeu7BX5BRgFkRrx6JzcZpW9Jn0r3GOkdSqGZG85soUxNX4GN*4gJlqjfCg81cDZAi5NqiEosZjJUXwZ2677ll3OCOUaS31/7v7qF9NN1XdlNc1hrI8kQfmtbRNM3EOybwAoFTHG76rqRos

I have tried to convert this string into a `byte[]` array using following code :

```
textFIR = new NBioAPI.Type.FIR_TEXTENCODE();
UInt32 r = m_NBioAPI.GetTextFIRFromHandle(hCapturedFIR, out textFIR, true);

string sr = "";
if (textFIR != null)
{
    sr = textFIR.TextFIR;
    byte[] src = new byte[sr.Length*sizeof(char)];

    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(sr.ToCharArray(),0,src,0,src.Length);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(src);
    System.Drawing.Image FP = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
    FP.Save("G:\\TempFP.Jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

But on `Image.FromStream(ms)` I am getting "Parameter is not valid." exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET String to byte Array C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14360257/109702, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11730373/109702,

Comment: "I have converted the fingerprint data to a text format" - What type was the fingerprint data to begin with?  a byte array?

Comment: No they dont provide a simple byte array. They want users to play with their TYPES only.

Comment: I am uising NITGEN's NITGEN.SDK.NBioBSP..And the fingerprint data type is "NBioAPI.Type.HFIR hCapturedFIR". And "m_NBioAPI.Capture(out hCapturedFIR, NBioAPI.Type.TIMEOUT.DEFAULT, m_WinOption)" this line gives hCapturedFIR.

Comment: Are you sure that the data in textFIR.TextFIR is an image, and not some form of fingerprint description data? Those bytes don't look like a BMP header or JPEG file preamble.

Comment: This is what I found in NITGEN's developer guide : All fingerprint data is used as the type of handle, binary or encoded text found in the NBioBSP
Class Library module.
Fingerprint data will be entered into the handle of FIR property upon successful enrollment, and it can be returned as the type of binary or
encoded text. So textFIR is an encoded Fingerprint data, I suppose. Do you know any other SDK which prvides APIs to convert finger print data to byte array or a JPEG form?

Comment: Take the image and save it to your file system called foo.jpg and double click on it. If you can't open it then it's not in any recognized image format. Windows will open .png and .gif files even if they are called something.jpg.

Comment: You can also check file formats by looking at through first few bytes of the file and matching them here: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't have experience with the particular library you're using, I can see some obvious problems with your code and expect them to be causing the issue. Check these two lines of your code:

```
string sr = "";
byte[] src = new byte[sr.Length*sizeof(char)];
```

`sr` is an empty string at this time, so sr.Length will be zeroand the byte array will also be zero-length, therefore `BlockCopy` will not be able to write anything to it. You should move this second line inside the `if` block, after the line `sr = textFIR.TextFIR;`.

Comment: I tried what you told me to do. But it still gives me the same exception. Parameter is not Valid.

Comment: I am not sure abut that..Because textFIR is an object which encodes actual finger print data (NBioAPI.Type.HFIR) into a text.

Comment: I just went through their documentation (http://www.nitgen.com.br/download/EN_eNBSP_SDK_Programmer's_Guide_DC1-0017A_Rev_J.pdf). Looks like there's more to it than simply converting into a memory stream. Nowhere do they mention the exact image format they are using.

Comment: Any idea on this dotNET? I am stuck on this since last week. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try Tejas's idea. I don't have either the hardware or the software with me, so it is a bit difficult for me to experiment with it.

Answer (score 1):

The text in `TextFIR` member is neither a valid base64 encoded data or an image data.
It is a multi-byte text data used to store and verify with other FIR.

Use the API in NImgConv.dll to get an image from the FIR data.

Comment: But NImgConv.dll is written in cpp and delphi. I dont have its c# classes. the version of my Sdk is 3.12. It doe not include c# classes for this. Have u done this in c#? Can u send me an example code if u have done this?

Comment: If it is a COM component then regsvr32 NImgConv.dll and add ref from COM tab in VS otherwise follow the instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569603/using-c-class-dll-in-c-sharp-application

Comment: I am new to .NET and developing field. I tried regsvr32 NImgConv.dll And got following error : The module "NImgConv.dll" was loaded but entry-point DllRegister was not found. Make sure that NImgConv.dll is a valid DLL or OCX file and try again. Any Idea? I did not get the second option.

Comment: It might not be a COM component; try following the instructions from the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569603/using-c-class-dll-in-c-sharp-application

Comment: I am sorry but I dont even have an option for creating C++/CLI projects in my VS. I am totally new to this.

Comment: Ok..I get it..I have to create a class library project. i have created it. But how to make it depend on unmanaged dll?

Answer (score 0):

You should try [FromBase64string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to convert it to byte array.

```
public static  byte[] StringToBytes(string streamString)
{
   return Convert.FromBase64String(streamString);
}
```

To make sure your base64string is valid, you can check it like

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,**your base 64 string**" />
```

Check out [this](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter/Create) link for more info.

Comment: I got following exception on trying to do this :
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the string is in Base64 format, so you can use this functions to convert your string to Bytes[] and then use another function to convert Bytes[] to image.

```
    internal bool SaveBytesToFile(string fileFullPath, byte[] stream)
    {
        if (stream.Length == 0) return false;
        try
        { 
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileFullPath, (int)stream.Length))
                {
                    fileStream.Write(stream, 0, stream.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Write Error log
                errorhandler.Write(ex);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Write Error log
            errorhandler.Write(ex);
            return false;
        }

    }

    internal byte[] StringToBytes(string streamString)
    {
        return Convert.FromBase64String(streamString);
    }

    internal string BytesToString(byte[] stream)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(stream);
    }
```

Comment: I can not convert this string to byte array. I get following exception on trying to do this : 
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters