# Looping Through XML File VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, flowlayoutpanel

i have XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Database.-->
<Disease>

<Name id="1">Info1
<SubArticle>Info1</SubArticle>
<MainArticle>Info1</MainArticle>
<Image>Info1</Image>
</Name>

<Name id="2">Info2
<SubArticle>Info2</SubArticle>
<MainArticle>Info2</MainArticle>
<Image>Info2</Image>
</Name>

<Name id="3">Info3
<SubArticle>Info3</SubArticle>
<MainArticle>Info3</MainArticle>
<Image>Info3</Image>
</Name>

</Disease>
```

and i have UserControl :

[image]

and i have a FlowLayoutPanel which have an FlowDirection (TopDown)

I need to make the program add new UserControl in the FlowLayoutPanel with the Information in the XML File 
Examble:
The Program will add 3 UserControl in the Panel

```
UserControl1 =  <Name id="1">
UserControl2 =  <Name id="2"> 
UserControl3 =  <Name id="3">
```

...etc

How can i do this ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Currently, it's not even clear whether you have trouble reading the file or changing the control.

Comment: the propem not in the user control , but i need a code read all elements in the xml file and show it in the labels in usercontrol

Comment: The 'and' in your sentence indicates that they are two separate problems. If you approach them as such you may very well find the answers to them (1, How to read an XML file and 2, How to show a text in a label in a usercontrol). After that, you can simply combining by using the output of 1 as the input of 2.

Comment: i know how to read xml file but all the usercontrols will get the information only from the first element

Comment: i mean how can i make a loop get the info from the xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Imports System.Xml
Module Module1

    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument
        doc.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim names As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Name")

        Dim diseases As New List(Of Disease)
        For Each name As XmlNode In names
            Dim newDisease As New Disease
            diseases.Add(newDisease)

            newDisease.id = name.Attributes("id").Value
            newDisease.text = name.InnerText
            newDisease.subArticle = name.SelectSingleNode("SubArticle").InnerText
            newDisease.mainArticle = name.SelectSingleNode("MainArticle").InnerText
            newDisease.image = name.SelectSingleNode("Image").InnerText


        Next

    End Sub

    '  <Name id="1">
    '  Info1
    '  <SubArticle>Info1</SubArticle>
    '  <MainArticle>Info1</MainArticle>
    '  <Image>Info1</Image>
    '</Name>

End Module
Public Class Disease
    Public id As Integer
    Public text As String
    Public subArticle As String
    Public mainArticle As String
    Public image As String
End Class
​
```

Comment: thanks for the code , but i have 1 proplem , how can i put the image in the xml file in a picture box , i get error (cannot convert string to drawing.image ?

Comment: Does the XML contain image?  You need to change type in class from string to image.  I just used string because that is what you posted.

Comment: no the xml will have the path of the image , so how can i change the path (String) into image (System.Deaw) ?

Comment: See webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360257/convert-byte-to-image.  You need to use Image.FromStream().   String to image usually give problems, use byte[] instead.

Comment: i solve it by using Article.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(newDisease.image)
thank you for the code