# How can I write MemoryStream to byte[]

Tags: c#, stream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a byte array from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream)

I'm trying to create text file in memory and write it `byte[]`. How can I do this?

```
public byte[] GetBytes()
{
    MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
    TextWriter tx = new StreamWriter(fs);

    tx.WriteLine("1111");
    tx.WriteLine("2222");
    tx.WriteLine("3333");

    tx.Flush();
    fs.Flush();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(bytes,0,fs.Length);

    return bytes;
}
```

But it does not work because of data length

Comment: An object of type MemoryStream has the Property "ToArray()". There you get the byte[]

Comment: Will this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream ?

Comment: @yan.kun The closed original had only the first line when closed. He's added more info since, as well as - for some reason - posting this duplicate.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

How about:

```
byte[] bytes = fs.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code:

```
public byte[] GetBytes()
{
MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter tx = new StreamWriter(fs);

tx.WriteLine("1111");
tx.WriteLine("2222");
tx.WriteLine("3333");

tx.Flush();
fs.Flush();
byte[] bytes = fs.ToArray();
return bytes;
}
```

Comment: +1. note that using `using` instead of `Flush` is much safer. Also requires somewhat unusual code for MemoryStream to be accessible after Dispose - need to create MemoryStream before `using (ms)`...

Answer (score 3):

```
byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        b.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
        TextWriter tx = new StreamWriter(fs);

        tx.WriteLine("1111");
        tx.WriteLine("2222");
        tx.WriteLine("3333");

        tx.Flush();
        fs.Flush();

        fs.Position = 0;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        return bytes;
    }
```