# unexpected char when parsing json string

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I am serializing an object to a stream to store as file and then retrieving and trying to deserialize the object, but get an error parsing. Below is code:

```
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
var output = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8);
writer.Write(content);
writer.Flush();
//write to some file...


//when reading the file
Stream filestream;
//filestream opens some file stream
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){
int read;
while((read = filestream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0){
ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
//encounters error here. I can see that first few chars of the string are question marks.
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
```

Comment: My quickest guess is that your buffer is too small and the content is larger than 4096 bytes so you are not reading the whole thing back.

Comment: Side points: I hope this is pseudo-code because you need `using` blocks. You can use `CopyTo` instead of looping

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas. Are you getting an exception?

Try encapsulating your write & reads into functions and wrap the memoryStream and streamWriter in using statements as well

```
using var writer = new StreamWriter(...
```

Additionally you don't need to set the length of the buffer to 4096, that's probably messing up your encoding. Read your memorystream to an array like so

```
var buffer = ms.ToArray();
```

[How can I write MemoryStream to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443131/how-can-i-write-memorystream-to-byte)

It looks like you're having an issue copying the memory between the 2 memory streams though. Ideally you would write and read to a file or some other source rather than between 2 memory stream objects but you can copy the contents directly using a copyto

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-6.0

Edit: Adding pseudocode

Assuming your content has been read into
`Stream filestream;`

```
using var MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
filestream.CopyTo(ms);
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
```

Comment: yes i'm first putting it into S3 and then later reading it. I combined the two to keep it brief and only posted relevant parts.

Comment: You're making it too complicated. You don't need to do any loops, just copy your Stream filestream to a MemoryStream like in the link and call ToArray on the memorystream to get the bytes.