# Saving image from a URL

Tags: c#, .net, image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I've been hitting wall after wall trying to save an image from a URL in Windows Phone 7. I've tried http://imagetools.codeplex.com/ and WritableBimap, but I always hit problems with things either not loading (height is zero because the image hasn't loaded, or other cross-thread exceptions (given I'm using a background thread). Is there a simple library which lets me **save and resize** images from a URL?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: The problem is I'm doing it from a background thread and trying to save to `IsolatedStorage`. The image just won't load. I've tried using a `ManualResetEvent`, loading it in a `WebClient`, using `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and setting the reset event at the end of everything, and still the image has a width/height of zero when I come to save it.

Comment: Are you sure that the url is correct? (ends in jpeg or png or something like that) and when you put the url into Google Chrome (like what other browser would you use) it displays an image. Apart from that it is difficult to see what's going on without code to be honest. @Echilon

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **WebClient** or **WebRequest** at the moment?

**MediaLibrary.SavePicture** might also work

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture.aspx

These are also **official** Microsoft libraries so they may work better than external libraries.

For resizing, you might be interested in checking out the highly recommended http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/silverlight/windows-phone.htm

You may also be interested in this article from a Microsoft blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/09/resizing-images-in-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Currently I've tried with `WebClient` and using `OpenReadAsync`. MediaLibrary.SavePicture looks good but doesn't tackel resizing, so I'm still stuck with my first problem.

Comment: @Echilon you should check my updated answer, I think you might find the article useful. Please upvote, and checkmark in case it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

To download and store an image, you need to do this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://i.imgur.com/IgomXCN.jpg");

request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback((result) =>
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
        byte[] content = ReadFully(response.GetResponseStream());

        MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();
        lib.SavePictureToCameraRoll("Test Picture", content);
    }), null);
```

**ReadFully** is a function documented by Jon Skeet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/221941/303696) and is used to convert the stream to a byte array. [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx) is a part of the **Microsoft.Xna.Framework** assembly, as mentioned in one of the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [SimpleImage.Resizer](http://nuget.org/packages/Simple.ImageResizer)

The source is available on [github](https://github.com/terjetyl/Simple.ImageResizer).

The author has also setup a [demo on apphb](http://imageresizer.apphb.com/) if you want to see it in action.

Comment: Overkill for what the author wants to do.

Comment: @DenDelimarsky - Author has already indicated [ImageTools](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/). IMHO, the link I gave offers a simpler option. But looking at MediaLibrary, I get that its an even simpler option. Thanks.