# Cannot deserialize

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion

I have this code, which restore message queue (serialized) from SQLite

```
public void Restore()
{
    try
    {
        const string databaseName = @"C:\Code\C#\WcfService\WcfService\mainDB.db3";
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};", databaseName));
        connection.Open();
        try
        { 
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM dump ORDER BY DId DESC limit 1", connection);
            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var info = (byte[])reader["DBinaryData"];
                Queue<Message> deserializedData = GetDeserializedMessages(info);
                var data = MergeQueueMessage(deserializedData);
                Logger.Log(data.ToString());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Log(e.Message);
    }
}

    public Queue<Message> GetDeserializedMessages(byte[] source)
    {
        Queue<Message> messages = null;

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(source))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            messages = (Queue<Message>)formatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }
        return messages;
    }
```

But i have a problem: can't deserialize information from field "DBinaryData";
My table in DB contain:

1. DId (integer, primary key)
2. DTime (Text)
3. DBinaryData (Blob) // dump of message queue as serialized object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
reader["DBinaryData"].ToArray();
```

to serialize your binary data into a byte[].

i.e.

```
byte[] info = reader["DBinaryData"].ToArray();
```

Comment: I get information from reader["DBinaryData"] as Object. Object don't know something about ToArray() method.

Comment: I think this is your problem and what you're trying to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream

Comment: but how to use that with reader["DBinaryData"]?

Comment: Use it in GetDeserializedMessages() - it's about the same code as the example.

Comment: im try as Queue<Message> deserializedData = GetDeserializedMessages((byte[])reader["DBinaryData"]) but get exception: end of Stream encountered before parsing was completed