# Cannot convert System.IO.Stream to Byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an image which is of type `varbinary` in db.

In BO layer, it is declared as `Byte[]`.

```
    public Byte[] Image
    {
         get { return p_image; }
         set { p_image = value; }
    }
```

To assign its value in BO layer, I used

```
objBO.Image = FileUploadControl.FileContent
```

Its throws the error

> Connot convert System.IO.Stream to Byte[]

Can anybody help in choosing the parameter of `FileUploadControl` that can be converted to `Byte[]`?

Comment: You have the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`FileUpload.FileBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes.aspx) property to get `Byte[]` from the `FileUploadControl`

> Gets an array of the bytes in a file that is specified by using a
>   [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control.

```
FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
Byte[] fileBytes = fileUpload.FileBytes;
```

> The FileUpload control does not automatically read the file from the
>   client. You must explicitly provide a control or mechanism to allow
>   the user to submit the specified file. For example, you can provide a
>   button that the user can click to upload the file. **The code that you
>   write to save the specified file could call the FileBytes property,
>   which returns the contents of the file.**

Comment: Very simple solution with clear explanation. Thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

instead of `FileUploadControl.FileContent` you must use `FileUploadControl.FileBytes`

`Filecontent` gives you you the stream, so either convert the stream into bytes or directly use `FileBytes`