# System.IO.MemoryStream to Byte

Tags: c#, byte

I'm writing a service to get `VARBINARY` information from a Vendor's service and insert it in to a database on my network.  In the example below `oResponseObject` is declared as an `Object`, `ExecuteURL` is an `Object`, but is returned as `System.IO.MemoryStream`.

```
strURL += APIHelper.GetQueryStringParameter("image_id", reader["ImageID"].ToString()); 
Object oResponseObject = ExecuteURL(strURL, true);

byte[] bytes =  ???
```

QUESTION:  How do I convert that `MemoryStream` so that it will work with the `byte[]`?  I've already tried `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`.  It will go to the Array and insert in to the database with no problem. When I try to render the graphic I get an error indicating that it's either too big or the file is corrupt.

Comment: Added to Subject Line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a byte array from a stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
byte[] bytes = ((MemoryStream)oResponseObject).GetBuffer();
```

Comment: I'm getting an 'InvalidCastEsception' error now.  The error that I'm getting now says:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.

Other things I've tried it says that it's a MemoryString.

Comment: You said what's returned is a `MemoryStream`. This is clearly not the case. You seem to be getting back a string, so you need to tell us what's in that string. Is it base64-encoded? Is it just the file name? What is it? My answer is for the question how to get the bytes from a `MemoryStream`.