# Converting Stream to byte[] array always returns 0 length in windows phone 8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, stream

I have a Stream received from a `PhotoResult` of `photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)` event handler.

The `e.ChosenPhoto` itself a Stream so I assign it to `Stream stream`. And I converted it to byte[] array using the method below:

```
    public static byte[] ReadImageFile2(Stream mystream)
    {
        // The mystream.length is still full here.
        byte[] imageData = null;
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(mystream))
        {
            imageData = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(mystream.Length));
        }
        // But imageData.length is 0
        return imageData;
    }
```

I don't know what is wrong with the BinaryReader, it returns `imageData` with just 0 length. Tried to cast type as `br.ReadBytes((int)mystream.Length)` but still doesn't work.

Also tried all of the answers in [Creating a byte array from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream) but still not working. Maybe my `e.ChosenPhoto` cannot be used as a normal Stream.

Thank you.

Comment: Whats `mystream.Length`?

Comment: it's the length of the `stream` from `e.ChosenPhoto` which I pass into the method: `ReadImageFile2(stream)`

Comment: I see your problem has been solved, but for the record I was asking what the *value* of `mystream.Length` was.

Comment: Do you mean the type? If it is then `.length` returns a `long` type.

Comment: I meant the value. Is it 0 or is it 198723. It doesn't matter by now anyways, as it is obviously not 0.

Comment: The length of `mystream` is not 0, just `imageData`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you may have to set the position of the stream to 0 before reading it:

```
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(mystream))
{
    mystream.Position = 0;
    imageData = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(mystream.Length));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! Didn't event notice that