# Image from Stream - only works on first page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a code snippet that is converting Stream to byte[] and later displaying that as an image in aspx page.

Problem is when first time page loads image is being displayed, but not displaying for later requests (reload etc).

Only difference I observed is Stream position in 'input' (ConvertStreamtoByteArray) is 0 for the first time and subsequent calls is > 0. How do I fix this?

```
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = "image/pjpeg";
context.Response.BinaryWrite(ConvertStreamtoByteArray(imgStream));
context.Response.End();

private static byte[] ConvertStreamtoByteArray(Stream input)
{
    var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I think the source is : [Creating a byte array from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream)
I think the code snippet is from above link, I see everything matches except for method name.

Comment: So where do you initialize `imgStream`?

Comment: imgStream is in Session.

Comment: You can't, or at least shouldn't, store a stream in the session.

Answer (score 0):

You're (most likely) holding a reference to `imgStream`, so the same stream is being used every time `ConvertStreamtoByteArray` is called.

The problem is that streams track their `Position`.  This starts at 0 when the stream is new, and ends up at the end when you read the entire stream.

Usually the solution in this case is to set the `Position` back to 0 prior to copying the content of the stream.

*In your case,* you should probably 1) convert `imgStream` to a byte array the first time it's needed 2) ***cache this byte array and not the stream*** 3) dispose and throw away `imgStream` and 4) pass the byte array to the `Response` from this point onwards.

See, this is what happens when you copypasta code from the internets.  Weird stuff like this, repeatedly converting the same stream to a byte array (waste of time!), and you end up not using [the framework to do your work for you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx).  Manually copying streams is so 2000s.

Comment: This was not my code and I am just trying to fix a bug. But I do copy the code from internet sometimes. I must admit that!