# I use XLABS to pick images from a gallery. How to get the filepath of the image?

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using XLABS in my xamarin forms project and I try to reach the underlying data of the image but I am not sure how to get it with my current code. I have a viewmodel and a page where I use the function and the function itself works fine. I can pick an image and get it. But I want to get the path/filedata.

My viewmodel:

```
public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return _ImageSource; }
        set { SetProperty (ref _ImageSource, value); }
    }

private byte[] imageData;

    public byte[] ImageData { get { return imageData; } }

    private byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public async Task SelectPicture()
    {
        Setup ();

        ImageSource = null;


        try
        {
            var mediaFile = await _Mediapicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions
                {
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                    MaxPixelDimension = 400
                });

            VideoInfo = mediaFile.Path;
            ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Status = ex.Message;
        }
    }


    private static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
    {
        double rtn_value = (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;

        return rtn_value;
    }
```

My page where I use it:

```
MyViewModel photoGallery = null;

photoGallery = new MyViewModel ();

private async void btnPickPicture_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await photoGallery.SelectPicture (); 
        imgPicked.Source = photoGallery.ImageSource; //imgPicked is my image x:name from XAML.

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MediaFile](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/54c6660ff62011a2c8a9c82512eb090edfaeb199/src/Platform/XLabs.Platform/Services/Media/MediaFile.cs) has a Path property.  You even refer to it in your ViewModel

```
VideoInfo = mediaFile.Path;
```

Comment: Ah ok. But how do I go from there? When I take out the Imagesource from the gallery now I do only get a "Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource" and I guess I would need a png/jpg to be able to store it externally?

Comment: Should I make a new thread with the title "How do I get the underlying data from the image I pick from a gallery?"

Comment: The MediaFile has both a Path and a Source (stream) property.  Either use a stream or a file IO operation to read the data.

Comment: Okay. Should I read the data in my viewmodel or in my page where I use the function?

Comment: Am i not using the method u are explaining here "ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);"?

Comment: Yes, you are.  If you want to read the raw image data from a stream, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream

Comment: I am using that code as well right? private byte[] imageData;

    public byte[] ImageData { get { return imageData; } }

    private byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

Comment: You have it in your code, but it doesn't appear that you are ever using ReadStream().

Comment: private byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)

Comment: That is the definition of your method.  You never call it anywhere else in your code, so it is never executed.

Comment: Ahh okay. That might be the problem then. I will make a new thread with that question then. Thanks alot Jason.