# adding to azure blob storage with stream

Tags: c#, asynchronous, azure-storage, filestream, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to add an `IFormFile` received via a .net core web API to an azure blob storage. These are the properties I have set up:

```
static internal CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount => 
    new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(AccountName, AccessKey, AccessKeyName), true);

// Create a blob client.
static internal CloudBlobClient BlobClient => StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Get a reference to a container 
static internal CloudBlobContainer Container(string ContainerName) 
                        => BlobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName);

static internal CloudBlobContainer ProfilePicContainer 
        => Container(ProfilePicContainerName);
```

Now I use the `ProfilePicContainer` like this:

```
var Container = BlobStorage.ProfilePicContainer;
string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + Path.GetExtension(ProfileImage.FileName);
var blockBlob = Container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
var fileStream = ProfileImage.OpenReadStream();
fileStream.Position = 0;
await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
```

This gives me the following error:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'
>
> Inner Exception
>   ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.

When debugging, I have noticed even before `fileStream.Position = 0` it's position is already 0. However I added the line since I was getting this error.  Also right at the await line, the `fileStream`'s `_disposed` is set to false.

Moreover regarding the blob connection I have tried setting an invalid value for the string constant `AccessKey` and it shows the exact same error. Which means I have no idea if it is even connection. I have checked all values within `blobBlock` in the debugger, but I have no idea how to verify if it is connected.

Comment: It sounds like `fileStream` is already closed rather than a problem with the azure storage sdk? Are you able to access the `fileStream` stream at all? Can you write it to disk with something like `using (var testStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.GetTempFileName())) fileStream.CopyTo(testStream)`?

Comment: yes have tried the fileStream to write to file and to write to bytes. both works fine.

Comment: Try putting the stream in a using block

Comment: i had tried that earlier. I had other errors and saw recommendations online that said to not use using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some issue when trying to write directly from the stream. I was able to run the code by converting the stream to a byte array.

```
await blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(ReadFully(fileStream, blockBlob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes),
                            0, (int)fileStream.Length);
```

The `ReadFully` was a modification over this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/221941

```
static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input, int size)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, size)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will there be any comparative performance issues with multiple files 50 MB to 300 MB?

Comment: i haven't tested that yet. but you can always use the simulated offline blob storage and test this out