# Web service File Stream to Byte[] to FileStream to pdf failing C#

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, pdf

I am trying to create a `web service` that returns a `pdf` file as a `byte[]` and then the app that consumes it grabs the `byte[]` and saves it as a `pdf` file and then opens it. The file fails to open at the end.

Here is the **Web Service** that returns a `byte[]`

```cs
[WebMethod]
public byte[] XXXX(int fileID)
{
    try
    {
        using (EntitiesModel dbContext = new EntitiesModel())
        {   
            string fileFullPath = .....
            .......     
            if (fileFullNamePath != null)
            {
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileFullNamePath, FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
                int len = fileStream.Length.ToInt();
                Byte[] documentContents = new byte[len];
                fileStream.Read(documentContents, 0, len);
                fileStream.Close();
                return documentContents;
```

Then it is called from an **app** with the following code

```cs
string soap = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf - 8\"?>" +
              "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
              "<soap:Body>" +
              "<XXXX xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
              "<fileID>XXXXX</fileID>" +
              "</XXXX>" +
              "</soap:Body>" +
              "</soap:Envelope>";
string localhostContext = @"http://localhost:3381/";
string webserviceAddress = @"XXXX/XXXX/XXXXX.asmx";
string url = localhostContext + webserviceAddress ;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.ContentLength = soap.Length;
request.Timeout = 20000;
request.Method = "POST";
using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(soap);               }
    }
}
byte[] bytes;
try
{
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    bytes = ReadFully(response.GetResponseStream());
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    throw;
}

private byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}

FileStream objfilestream =
                new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
objfilestream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
objfilestream.Close();
var process = Process.Start(fileName);
```

The code runs fine and creates a `pdf` and then tries to open that `pdf`. But the file can not be opened. Adobe Acrobat gives the error

```
Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open XXX.pdf because it is either not a 
supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it 
was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).
```

Because I am not getting an error in the code I am at a loss to know where the error is that is not creating the proper file.

There was an issue with the `Stream` variable called `input` was not giving length so I used `Jon Skeet's` suggestion here [Stackoverflow:Creating a byte array from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream)

```
new byte[16*1024];
```

rather than

```
new byte[input.length]
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the resulting PDF in a text editor like Notepad++? The response is probably base64-encoded or otherwise wrapped.

Comment: @CodeCaser It opens in NotePad++ as 1 line.

Comment: @DarrenWood I think he's hinting that your data might be corrupt. At least shows us what you see on your screen. Kindly paste some example NotePad++ text here or else give a link to your not-working PDF file (share file via: Dropbox or Google Drive, etc).

Comment: @CodeCaster shouldn't that be _"open resulting PDF in a **hex** editor"_? Easier that way to check if bytes are a valid (PDF) format.

Comment: @VC.One I will post the file tommorw. I am away from desk now. Thanks

Comment: @DarrenWood No worries. Also you likely don't want `memoryStream.Position = 0;` to be inside the While loop since it's resetting position each time to zero. You're overwriting each previous `memoryStream.Write`. I think that's why you end up with just 1 line.

Comment: @VC.One That very much looks like the issue (at least like one major of it). You should make that an answer.

Comment: @VC.One will I implement tomorrow morning

Comment: @VC.One  I have removed the code memoryStream.Position = 0 from the while loop but I am still getting the error. I noticed that the soap xml tags with the byte[] in a XXXResult tag are saved to the file. I am not sure how to extract the byte[] path. I am researching this. The soap XML tags and the binary file are still on 1 line which is strange.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes it was wrapped in the SOAP Xml response . How do I extract the Byte[] from that?

Comment: @CodeCaster The solution you commented was correct. The response was both wrapped in Soap XML and base64 encoded. If you want to provide that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @VC.One Your comment was part of the solution so if you provide that as answer I will upvote it.

Comment: @DarrenWood maybe share **your** solution to finally get it working. Could be useful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were three things wrong.

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

in the while loop was problematic so I removed it.

Secondly when reading the stream. What it returned was the `SOAP` `XMl` message with the encoded `base64` string in the the XXXXResult `XML` tag. So I had to extract that.

Finally I had to use

```
byte[] fileResultBytes  = Convert.FromBase64String(resultString);
```

to get the byte[] from the resultString extracted from the `SOAP` message. In the test `SOAP` message, that can be generated locally, it tells you the type of this result string. I missed that initially.

Thanks to `VC.One` and `CodeCaster` for their correct suggestions.