# How to get JSON body from the stream in C# efficiently?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, utf8json

I am using Utf8 json library to deserialize my JSON using `DeserializeAsync` method of `JsonSerializer` class. And sometimes I am seeing it is throwing exception as -

```
Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

So it looks like my JSON data has a value that's too large to fit in one of our object's properties causing this overflow exception. Below is the code I got where I am trying to print the json which is bad and causing this `Arithmetic Overflow` error but it's not logging that JSON whenever this exception happens.

```
using (var content = httpResponseMessage.Content)
{
    if (content == null) return (default(T), statusCode);

    using (var responseStream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        try
        {
            deserializedValue = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(responseStream, formatResolver);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var bodyString = (ex as JsonParsingException)?.GetUnderlyingByteArrayUnsafe();
            var error = (bodyString != null) ? $"Bad json: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bodyString)}" : "Cannot Deserialize JSON";
            logger.logError(error, ex.Message, "Deserialization Exception", ex.StackTrace, (int)statusCode);
            return (default(T), HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason `bodyString` is coming as null whenever this exception happens and that's why my condition is not getting evaluated to get the JSON body. My understanding was that it will throw `JsonParsingException` but looks like it is throwing some other exception.

Is there any way to get JSON body whenever this exception happens? or maybe write this in a better way to get JSON whenever this exception happens efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You wrote that you got an "Arithmetic Overflow" error, so the actual type of exception in the catch is probably `OverflowException`, not `JsonParsingException`
2. I think you should get `bodyString` from `responseStream`. You can reset the stream with `responseStream.Position = 0` and read the body as a byte array from it.

Comment: Thanks for point 1 and I will take a look but confuse on your point 2. Can you provide an example on how to do it efficiently?

Comment: You can use MemoryStream. The technique was described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream.